# SwiftUI, navigationBarItems not working after programatically dismissing modal

Tags: swift, swiftui

Using SwiftUI,

I show a modal and then programmatically dismiss it.
The issue is, the second time, that `navigationBarItems` are not responsive and I can't press on them anymore.

If I dismiss the modal using the swipe gesture then it works fine but not when I call `self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()`

HomeView.swift

```
struct HomeView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc;
    
    @State private var isSureToResetCounter = false;
    var body: some View {

        func handleLeadingBtnPress() -> Void {
            self.isSModalPresented = true;
        }
                
        return
            NavigationView {
                VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 20.0) {
                    Spacer(minLength: 10)
                  // ...
                }
                .padding(20)
                .background(Color.secondary)
                .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                .navigationBarTitle(Text(""), displayMode: .inline)
                    
                .navigationBarItems(
                    leading:
                    Button(action: handleLeadingBtnPress) {
                        Text("Save")
                            .foregroundColor(.textPrimary)
                    }.sheet(isPresented: self.$isSModalPresented) {
                        SaveModalView()
                            .environment(\.managedObjectContext, self.moc)
                            .modifier(SystemServices())
                    }, trailing:
                    NavigationLink(destination: ActivityListView()) {
                        Text("History")
                            .foregroundColor(.textPrimary)
                })
                    .gesture(tap)
        }
    }
}
```

SaveModalView.swift

```
struct SaveModalView: View {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) private var presentationMode
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc;
    //...
    func handleSaveActivity() -> Void {        
        let newActivity = Activity(context: self.moc);
        do {
            try moc.save();
        } catch {
            print("coulnd save activity")
        }
        AppStoreReviewManager.requestReviewIfAppropriate();
        self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
    }
//...
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:** The bug only seems to occur on the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug from SwiftUI on certain Xcode versions. I suggest you try latest version of Xcode and see if things work out.